# set GCP enviroment variables to access a bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I'm working with GCP buckets to store data, my first approach to read write files into/from the buckets was:

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name,credentials):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name) 

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name,credentials):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))
```

Which does works fine, but I wan to save it as envioment variables to not keep the files around all the time. As I understand it, google if the  credentials are not provided, changing:

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)
```

for:

```
client = storage.Client()
```

Then google with search for the default credentials, which can be set by doing:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Which I'm doing and don't get any error:

[image]

But when I try to access to the bucket I get the following error:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

I'm following the link, creating a new key:

[image]

And trying whit that one instead, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you run you code in the same terminal, with the same venv activated, that where you export your variable? Try to check the value before starting your code or at the beginning of your code for validating the value set.

Comment: Does this command display the contents of your service account file? `cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. If not, you have set the environment variable wrong, used the wrong path or filename, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because, the interpreter unable to fetch the login credentials needed to proceed.
`client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)`

On this line, are you mentioning just credentials or the path of the file, can you try importing the serviceaccount.json file and then try.
Solution:please refer below code snippet,
`from google.cloud import storage client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('serviecaccount.json')`

where as the 'serviecaccount.json' file i have kept in the same project repo